# CodeIgniter all the pages redirecting to home page?

Tags: php, javascript, apache, codeigniter

I have made a codeIgniter application. Its working oh so cool on my local, but when I deploy it to the main, all my pages are getting redirected to the home page.

I have the following directory structure:

---www

-----.htaccess

------codeIgniter (the application lives here).

My htaccess reads as follows

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 ^media
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ codeIgnite/$1

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|codeIgnite|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ codeIgnite/index.php/$1
```

And this is my config.php
`$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/codeIgnite/";` // or should it just be http://localhost/ ?

Is there some other config settings I need to change ? Please help.

My home page shows up just fine. Problem is with other pages. No matter what URL I give, I see my home page UI.

Comment: Replace `localhost` with your domain name (if you're really already deploy it)

Comment: Please tell me the base_url config item is actually in quotes :P

Comment: Hi Muhammad. I already did it. I was wondering should I have the /codeIgnite as well or should I just have the domain name ? And also its an https server, so I should add the https or http ?

Comment: HI Joe. Yes its in quotes. Sorry I missed it out while editing here. And my home page shows up just fine. Problem is with other pages. No matter what URL I give, I see my home page UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the $config['uri_protocol'] = "ORIG_PATH_INFO", fixed the issue.

Comment: I will do that.. But I need to wait for 2 days for that (thats what clicking on the tick says)..

Comment: I just have to leave a comment to say THANK YOU SO MUCH for coming back and answering your own question.  Three days of wrestling with someone else's ancient codeigniter setup is OVER thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the provided [.htaccess from CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite) and just set the `RewriteBase` to my subdirectory to get it to work properly.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /codeIgnite/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I want to have some folders outside the codeIgnite folder parallel to it as well. e.g. RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|codeIgnite|images|robots\.txt)

Comment: Are you using those folders from within your codeigniter application? Can't you just create the .htaccess in the root of your CI folder?

Comment: Those folders aren't used from my codeIgnite application. They contain some other pages. I want codeIgniter application to by my default home, but other pages should be accessible as with the respective path.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to put the .htaccess in the CodeIgniter folder and also you have to modify the  last line of your file to this
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /codeIgniter/index.php/$1 or
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /codeIgnite/index.php/$1
You dont have to do nothing in apache config only turn on the extension rewrite_module