# Pages redirecting to base URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess

Ive been using codeigniter CMS. It was working fine...until 4 days. I did play a bit with httpd.conf but it has .htaccess enabled and all so I am sure it might not be the problem . Whenever I click any page from home page of CMS it redirects to base_url.The login page of CMS appears fine and also logs into home page. The urls in the home page redirects to base URL.

Ive checked this question

[CodeIgniter all the pages redirecting to home page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245338/codeigniter-all-the-pages-redirecting-to-home-page)

Tried this solution by changing $config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO" to options mentioned. But it doesn't seem to be the solution. My .htaccess file reads

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Tried playing with config.php by changing base_url and all..but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea/help ?

Comment: [**Kindly do not place tags on the title.**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: Can you give an example of a url that is redirecting to the base_url() . Do non-cms sections work fine without redirecting? Have you made changes to the `config/routes.php`? You may need to show us your cms controllers as the `.htaccess` you posted above seems fine.

Comment: yeah this is the example of the URL http://www.mysite.com/admin_pages this redirects to http://www.mysite.com . No I have not made any changes to routes.php or any other file in codeigniter when it stopped working